# Ruby - sort_by using dynamic keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A",
        points: 20,
        victories: 4,
        goals: 5,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "B",
        points: 20,
        victories: 4,
        goals: 8,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "C",
        points: 21,
        victories: 5,
        goals: 8,
    }
]
```

To sort them using two keys I do:

```
array = array.group_by do |key| 
[key[:points], key[:goals]] 
end.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
```

But in my program, the sort criterias are stored in a database and I can get them and store in a array for example: `["goals","victories"]` or `["name","goals"]`.

How can I sort the array using dinamic keys?

I tried many ways with no success like this:

```
criterias_block = []
criterias.each do |criteria|
    criterias_block << "key[:#{criteria}]"
end

array = array.group_by do |key| 
    criterias_block 
end.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#sort` can do this

```
criteria = [:points, :goals]
array.sort_by { |entry|
  criteria.map { |c| entry[c] }
}

#=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"A", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>5},
#    {:id=>1, :name=>"B", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>8},
#    {:id=>1, :name=>"C", :points=>21, :victories=>5, :goals=>8}]
```

This works because if you sort an array `[[1,2], [1,1], [2,3]]`, it sorts by the first elements, using any next elements to break ties

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
criteria = ["goals", "victories"]
criteria = criteria.map(&:to_sym)
array = array.group_by do |key| 
    key.values_at(*criteria)
end.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)

# => [[{:id=>1, :name=>"A", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>5}, 
#      {:id=>1, :name=>"B", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>8}, 
#      {:id=>1, :name=>"C", :points=>21, :victories=>5, :goals=>8}]]
```

`values_at` returns an array of all the keys requested:

```
array[0].values_at(*criteria)
# => [4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing it like this.

**Code**

```
def sort_it(array,*keys)
  array.map { |h| [h.values_at(*keys), h] }.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
end
```

**Examples**

For `array` as given by you:

```
sort_it(array, :goals, :victories)
  #=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"A", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>5},
  #    {:id=>1, :name=>"B", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>8}, 
  #    {:id=>1, :name=>"C", :points=>21, :victories=>5, :goals=>8}]
sort_it(array, :name, :goals)
  #=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"A", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>5},
  #    {:id=>1, :name=>"B", :points=>20, :victories=>4, :goals=>8},
  #    {:id=>1, :name=>"C", :points=>21, :victories=>5, :goals=>8}]
```

For the first of these examples, you could of course write:

```
sort_it(array, *["goals", "victories"].map(&:to_sym))
```